# Invalid user identity in provided tenant implementing bot proactive message

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, botframework, microsoft-teams

I have a bot application developed in java sdk. To integrate with MS Teams, I have a connector has been created using Bot Framework and Spring Boot and a Bot Channels Registration on the Azure portal. Everything working properly. Now I'm trying to implement proactive messages by following this tutorial: https://www.vrdmn.com/2020/02/microsoft-bot-framework-v4-send.html

I can already make the bot send proactive messages on channels, but now I need to implement the post a proactive personal message to a user.

I can get data from a user:

`var user = await ((Conversations)connectorClient.Conversations).GetConversationMemberAsync(mentionUserPrincipalName, teamInternalId, default);`

[image]

But when running the line...

`var response = await connectorClient.Conversations.CreateConversationAsync(conversationParameters);`

...a bad request result is returned with the message "Invalid user identity in provided tenant":

[image]

Comment: Please verify the logged in user is part of the azure ad or tenant.

Comment: We are not able to repro the issue at our end. Could you please check [Send proactive messages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/bots/how-to/conversations/send-proactive-messages?tabs=dotnet) and [sample](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/main/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/16.proactive-messages). Try if that helps.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the user details using teams roster. To create a new conversation or conversation thread in a channel, you must have the correct ID. You can receive or retrieve this ID. Please check [Get the user ID, team ID or channel ID](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/bots/how-to/conversations/send-proactive-messages?tabs=dotnet#get-the-user-id-team-id-or-channel-id). You can also fetch the list the members of a team using teams roaster. Please check [Fetch the roster or user profile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/bots/how-to/get-teams-context?tabs=dotnet#fetch-the-roster-or-user-profile).